# Jquery, menu item highlighted too early on scroll

Tags: jquery

I have a page with 2 divs. The first one contains a list of items, the second one contains 1 section for each item of the list.
When scrolling down the second div, I'd like the correct li to be highlighted when its corresponding section is "active". The problem is that they get hightlighted before reaching correct section.
Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/acanana/pen/OVJjrQ) I made. And here's the Jquery function I use:

```
$('#event-details .content').on('scroll', function() {
    $('.event-title').each(function() {
        if($('#event-details .content').scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top) {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            console.log(id);
            $('.event-title').removeClass('active');
            $('#' + id).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

I guess the problem is on the conditions but I can't solve it. Any idea about that? Thank you!

Comment: Not the answer, but FYI there are many free libraries to do this, e.g. https://github.com/sxalexander/jquery-scrollspy

Comment: And looking at the code and HTML, it seems you're comparing the scrollTop of the right side with the offset from the left side... which seems wrong?

Comment: Hello, you are right, my bad, thank you. I updated the condition to `if($('#event-details .content').scrollTop() >= $('.event-' + id + '-details').offset().top)`, but now the first li is always highlighted.

Comment: Did you fix it since your comment? It didn't work at first, then I reloaded and it worked. :)

Comment: Yes, I moved the line `var id = $(this).attr('id');` before the condition. It works again, but items are still highlighted early :(. Is it working for you?

Comment: If you console.log the `offset().top` value, you'll see that it changes as you scroll... so you want to highlight the last one that has a negative `offset().top` basically... `if($('.event-' + id + '-details').offset().top < 0)` should work, though slightly inefficient (since it will highlight/dehighlight a few before stopping).

Comment: Indeed: `offset()` is the position relative to the document.

Comment: Used `if($('.event-' + id + '-details').offset().top <= $('.event-' + id + '-details').height() / 3) {` and it seems to be working properly. Updated codepen, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

By your comments *the first li is always highlighted.*

That's because it will always return 1 as the `scrollTop` is always greater than the first section offset.
So you will what to check where the section ends. That is the top offset plus the height of the section.

```
$('#event-details .content').on('scroll', function() {
    $('.event-title').each(function() {
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if($('#event-details .content').scrollTop() >= $('.event-' + id + '-details').offset().top &&
          /* here is what is needed in the condition */ 
          $('#event-details .content').scrollTop() <= $('.event-' + id + '-details').offset().top + $('.event-' + id + '-details').height()) {
            console.log(id);
            $('.event-title').removeClass('active');
            $('#' + id).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

NOTE: tweak it a little to change by your taste(e.g half of the height or any amount of pixel)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I updated the [codepen](http://codepen.io/acanana/pen/OVJjrQ) but items3,4 and 5 are still highlighted early...

Comment: By the way `id` should be unique. Try to change your ids'.

Comment: id on `<section class="details event-1-details">` was unintentional. Removed it, thanks for the reminder ;)